# Prove that the sum of 2 increasing sequences is also increasing.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Attempt 2:

Let’s refer to a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ as increasing after a while if the following is true:

$(\exists N \in \mathbb N)(\forall n \in\mathbb N)$$(n \leq N$ $\rightarrow$ $x_{n+1} \geq x_n)$.

Write a formal proof that if sequences $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and $\{y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ are both increasing after a
while, then the sequence $\{x_n + y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$
is also increasing after a while. (Make use of the definition of increasing after a while)

Proof: We must prove that $(\exists N \in N)(\forall n \in N)(n \geq N \rightarrow x_{n+1} + y_{n+1} \geq x_n + y_n)$. Since $x_n$ is increasing, it follows that there exists $N_1$ such that for all $n$ in the natural numbers, if $n \geq N$, then $x_{n+1} \geq x_n$. Similarly, since $y_n$ is increasing, it follows that there exists $N_2$ such that for all $n$ in the natural numbers, if $n \geq N$, then $y_{n+1} \geq y_n$. Choose $N_3 = \max(N_1, N_2)$. Let $n$ be a natural number. Suppose $n \geq N$.  It follows that $x_{n+1} + y_{n+1} \geq x_n +y_n$. This completes the proof.

Comment: You want that $x_{n+1} \geq x_n$ and $y_{n+1} \geq y_n$ for $n \geq N(x,y)$ holds. For which $N$ do you know, the first inequality holds, and for which $N$ do you know the second inequality holds (noting the $N$ in your definitions as $N(x)$ and $N(y)$ respectively.

Comment: your notation causes confusion.

Comment: You know that for n > N x_n increases but might not for  n < M.  For m > M y_n increases but m < M might not so what number *should* we choose.  The larger one, the smaller one, some third choice?

Comment: "Do I need to put n,m≥N,M instead?"  It is not at all clear what such a notation would mean.  Also you *aren't* adding $x_m + y_n$ you are adding $x_k + y_k$ so you need *one* variable $k > K$ for some variable.  What must K be.  If K < N then we don't know if $x_k$ is increasing for $N> k > K$.  If K < M then we don't know $x_k$ is increasing $M> k >K$.  So how can we solve this?  what must K be?

Comment: How does it look now?

Answer (score 0):

So if N and M are the numbers in the two sequences, simply choose the larger of the two and it will work in the definition of the sum of the two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Choose $N:=\max\{N',N''\}$, where $N'$ and $N''$are the respective indices for $x_n$ and $y_n$.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned in your proof, a sufficient condition for $ x_{n+1} + y_{n+1} \geq x_n + y_n$, is that both $x_{n+1}\geq x_n$ and $y_{n+1} \geq y_n$.

Since, for $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$, there exists $N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$, and for $(y_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$, there exists an $N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$, such that the two sequences are increasing, choose $N = $max$\{N_1,N_2\}$ for the third sequence.

Comment: Ah, okay. I will use this for my 2nd attempt.

Comment: How does it look now?

Comment: Your proof was correct earlier as well, it just needed this definition of $N$.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help!